# Pin It Button, Can it work with OG, just like Facebook like or G+?

Tags: button, plugins, pinterest

is there a way to make Pin It button work with OG

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=["pull from OG"]&media=["Pull from OG"]&description=["Pull from OG"]" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="vertical"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (w, d, load) {
 var script,
 first = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0],  
 n = load.length,
 i = 0,
 go = function () {
   for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) {
     script = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.async = true;
     script.src = load[i];
     first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);
   }
 }
 if (w.attachEvent) {
   w.attachEvent('onload', go);
 } else {
   w.addEventListener('load', go, false);
 }
}(window, document,
 ['//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js']
));    
</script>
```

Just wonder if this is something that someone has already figured out or not? Would be nice if this could work that way, will make life simple.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to make it work, but not sure if this would be the best way of doing it since it requires to use php echo to echo content of the open graph meta content.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Family Budget Spreadsheet for Excel"> 
<meta property="og:type" content="product"> 
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php $og_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; echo $og_url ?>"> 
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php $og_image = 'http://www.mysite.com/images/imageIneed.jpg' ; echo $og_image ?>">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Sites Name"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php $og_description = 'My page description'; echo $og_description ?>">
```

then added following code taken from Pinterest

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $og_url ?>&media=<?php echo $og_image ?>&description=<?php echo $og_description ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="vertical"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (w, d, load) {
 var script,
 first = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0],  
 n = load.length,
 i = 0,
 go = function () {
   for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) {
     script = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.async = true;
     script.src = load[i];
     first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);
   }
 }
 if (w.attachEvent) {
   w.attachEvent('onload', go);
 } else {
   w.addEventListener('load', go, false);
 }
}(window, document,
 ['//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js']
));    
</script>
```

It is working just fine, but I am sure there is much better way of doing this, so if you have one, please share it here.